# Save value after search in select multiple drop down

Tags: php

I have a select option drop down menu and it is multiple I use this jquery to select multi option value for my search [Here](http://www.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/)

I want after I submit my search form save the option value choose it

before I use the jquery to change my select menu I have use this code and it work for me

```
<select name="txt_status">
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'Scheduled') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="Scheduled">Scheduled</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'Cancelled') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'Pending') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'Done') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="Done">Done</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'In Progress') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
</select>
```

But after I use the jquery the value choose it don't appear again the change I make it for the jquery in my html that is

```
<select  name="txt_status[]"  multiple id="langOpt">
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'Scheduled') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="Scheduled">Scheduled</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'Cancelled') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'Pending') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'Done') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="Done">Done</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']) && $_POST['txt_status'] == 'In Progress') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="In Progress">In Progress</option>
</select>
```

I try to do that

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['txt_status']['0']) && $_POST['txt_status']['0'] == 'Scheduled') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>
```

for all the value and for each value i change the number 0,1,2,3,4...

But this didn't work also.

**How can I save the option value if I choose done and click submit the value done stay in the drop menu and if I choose 2 options done and cancelled the two value stay after submit the form**

Comment: Any help ???!!!

Comment: any suggestion ??!!!!